# Why does running gclient produce update errors?

Tags: v8, gclient, depottools

I cloned depot_tools according to http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up.

Then when I run "gclient" I get this error:

```
depot_tools update failed. Conflict in /usr/v8-7.7/depot_tools
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/v8-7.7/depot_tools/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Errors:
  failed to resolve infra/3pp/tools/git/linux-ppc64le@version:2.24.1.chromium.5 (line 27): no such package
  failed to resolve infra/3pp/tools/cpython/linux-ppc64le@version:2.7.17.chromium.22 (line 21): no such package
/usr/v8-7.7/depot_tools/bootstrap_python3: line 32: bootstrap-3.8.0.chromium.8_bin/python3/bin/python3: No such file or directory
WARNING: Your metrics.cfg file was invalid or nonexistent. A new one will be created.
Usage: gclient.py <command> [options]

Meta checkout dependency manager for Git.
```

I'm running on a ppc64le linux machine set with RHEL 8. I have the goal of trying to install v8 on the machine but first gclient needs to work.

I do have python 2.7.15 installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions issue. I just had to adjust the permissions of the folder I was in.

Comment: What adjustments you had to do?

Comment: @Miguel I had to make myself owner of the folder and gave myself 777 permissions. Not the cleanest way, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when python3 was my default python.
gclient is likely running under python3 and not python2, which causes these errors
You can use `pyenv` to manage multiple parallel installations of python.

Comment: I've set python 2 using `update-alternatives --config python`.

Comment: The error suggests it's stick picking up python3. If you read `gclient` code you see it looks for an environment variable `GCLIENT_PY3` and if not set to 1 simply invokes `python`.